# How to find all cycles of a String in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I have written a method in Ruby to find all the circular combination of a text

```
x = "ABCDE"
(x.length).times do
  puts x
  x = x[1..x.length] + x[0].chr
end
```

Is there a better way to implement this ?

Comment: i mean already existing methods ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach.

```
str = "ABCDE"
(0...str.length).collect { |i| (str * 2)[i, str.length] }
```

I used a range and `#collect` with the assumption that you'll want to do something else with the strings (not just print them).

Comment: `(str * 2)[i, str.length]` took me a few to get my heard around.  But then I realized it was genius.  Nice solution!

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

```
x = "ABCDE"
x.length.downto(0) do |i|
  puts x[i..-1] + x[0...i]
end
```

It concatenates the string from the current index to the end, with the begining to the current index.

This way you don't need to alter your original variable at all.

Answer (score 3):

You could write an enumerator.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class String
  def rotations
    Enumerator.new do|y|
      times = 0
      chars = split('')

      begin
        y.yield chars.join('')

        chars.push chars.shift
        times += 1
      end while times < chars.length
    end
  end
end
```

That way you can do things like this.

```
"test".rotations.each {|r| puts r}
```

Answer (score 2):

Combine the string to itself and get all consecutive elements of size n (n is length of original string) using [`Enumerable.each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003144).

```
s = "hello"
(s + s).split('').each_cons(s.size).map(&:join)[0..-2]

# ["hello", "elloh", "llohe", "lohel", "ohell"]
```

Comment: slight variation:  (s * 2).split('').each_cons(s.size).map(&:join)[0..-2]

Needn't do uniq just to cut out the last string in the array.